# Responsive CSS dont apply to php reference functions in WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

i have a question regarding a responsive WordPress theme. I have converted a bootstrap theme and made it usable for WordPress but i have a small problem. When i put tags like this

```
    <h2 class="blog-title"><?php the_title();?></h2>
```

this title that it retrieves is not responsive, same goes with `<?php the_content(); ?>`. But everything else works fine. Any thoughts? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `the_title()` just returns some text; there's nothing about it that could make something "responsive" or not. It's also kind of meaningless to say that *part* of a page is "not responsive", since responsive design is about altering the layout *of the page* based on the screen size etc.

Comment: When I add some random hard coded text in the blog title it acts responsively. Only these php references tend to jump out of the borders of the page.

Comment: The key will be to view the HTML source generated - the responsiveness is entirely a client-side thing, so cannot "know" that a Wordpress tag was used.

Comment: Have you got a demo page we could look at to see what is happening?